# Android ndk undefined reference error

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have a `C++`  source file, and I want to call a method from my `C++` file, but I dont know whats wrong.
Here is my cpp method:

```
static unsigned ALawEncode(uint8_t* dst, int16_t* src, size_t srcSize);
```

Here is where I would like to call my method:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "G711.h"

extern "C" {

    uint8_t* Java_com_example_qonclient_Codecs_encodeG711( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, int16_t* source ){

        size_t size0 = sizeof(source);
        G711 g711;
        uint8_t *dst;

        g711.ALawEncode(dst, source, size0);

        return dst;
    }

}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: You must either incorporate the method definition into the compilation process or build a library out of the source and then link it.

Comment: THank you, but how? sorry, but this is the first i use ndk...

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong? You get error messages? What messages?

Comment: BTW, your `com.example.qonclient.Codecs.encodeG711()` method cannot send or receive C pointers; it must be using Java **byte[]**. You should use JNI functions (e.g. [GetShortArrayElements()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17382")) to convert the Java array to C array and vice versa.